# Question about Oracle's interpretation of "host cpu utilization" in v$sysmetric view

Tags: oracle, view, performance, unix, performance-tuning

I am studying the v$sysmetric view from Oracle and trying to understand what is Oracle's interpretation of "Host CPU Utilization"

It says in the metric_unit as % busy/(idle + busy), but what is busy?  Is that the sum of usr + sys time?  I tried comparing the query results from v$sysmetric against output from mpstat but it didn't seem to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figures in the `v$sysmetric` view are aggregated from `v$osstat` over a period of time (either 15 or 60 seconds).

`v$osstat` figures should closely mirror what you'd see from a tool such as `iostat`, `sar`, `mpstat`, `top` or `nmon`, but they will never be identical as it is impossible to synchronise the performance monitoring tool data collection with the data collection performed by the Oracle `MMON` process. As a result, the aggregated data in `v$sysmetric` will also never perfectly match monitoring tool output, but should be pretty close.

`Busy%` is indeed `Usr%` + `Sys%`.